# Java path problems, 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. (javac too)

Tags: java, path, environment-variables

I know there are lot of questions like this but i tried their solutions and nothing.

While i try to javac file.java i get 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. And java file 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

My environment path is
[image]

(JAVA_HOME) C:\ProgramFIles\Java\jdk-15.0.2
and
(Path)
C:\ProgramFIles\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin
...

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the path. Correct me if I'm wrong but on Windows

`JAVA_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2` and `PATH` should start with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`.

Next time, just copy-paste the path from Windows Explorer to avoid this.

Comment: omfg thank u! Like i was trying to fix it half hour and that was just typo? Haha im stupid thx

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you haven't installed java on your system. Try entering:

```
java --version
```

If you don't get a version number, install java from it's official site: https://www.java.com/en/download/